# Ilya Puchka's ReadMoreTextView (UITextView subclass, iOS, Swift, CocoaPods)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextview, cocoapods

Fairly new to Xcode and Swift, brand new to CocoaPods, trying to implement this:
https://github.com/ilyapuchka/ReadMoreTextView

It implements a subclass of UITextView that can be limited to a particular number of lines and will display a "Read More" type button to expand the UITextView.

I seem to have installed the ReadMoreTextView pod successfully, but in the code below, on the line `let textView = ReadMoreTextView()`, Xcode is showing `Use of unresolved identifier ReadMoreTextView`.

I tried adding `import ReadMoreTextView` as suggested by Hao below. The error above went away, but I got `No such module ReadMoreTextView` on the import.

I am able to drag a UITextView from the Library into the View Controller and assign it the `ReadMoreTextView` class in the Identity Inspector, so the class is known to Xcode.  (The IBOutlet is connected to that UITextview, both of which probably shouldn't even be there?)

Hopefully, there is just some simple thing that I'm missing here.

The whole project is in a zip file here, if that would be helpful:
http://greendept.com/readmoretextview/

```
//  ViewController.swift
//  readmoretextview
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {     
    @IBOutlet var textView: UITextView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let textView = ReadMoreTextView()           
        textView.text = "When the saints go marching in, When the saints go marching in"           
        textView.maximumNumberOfLines = 3  
        textView.shouldTrim = true  
        textView.trimText = "Read more"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to install ReadMoreTextView with pods in my swift project.
this is my pod file:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
target 'podTest' do
  pod 'ReadMoreTextView'
end

use_frameworks!
```

I got some errors in ReadMoreTextView Framework. But when I exchanged the ReadMoreTextView.swift file with I've downloaded form github and solve some error, it's working. Here is the [Demo](https://github.com/PengHao/Demo/tree/master/ReadMorePodTest)

I think the file in pods is a old version.

Comment: I had actually tried that.  But I get "No such module ReadMoreTextView"

Comment: Sorry about that, I have tried to install pods, but failed, thank GWF! Would you please show me your project config in "Build Phases->Link Binary" and "Build Settings->Other Linker Flags"?

Comment: Hao - Thanks for your help, but I have decided to pursue another approach, at least for the time being.